# Large .htaccess file

Tags: regex, performance, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Will a large .htaccess file slow down your website performance? I'm not just talking about 301  redirects, I have quite a few Rewrite rules in my .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /$1 [R=301]

# If request ends in . or .php, redirect to 404
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} [a-z]\.(php)?\sHTTP
RewriteRule !404|checkout - [R=404]

# Removes need for .php extention
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/checkout/success
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./$1.php

# Prevents 500 internal error for e.g. /index/fakepage
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404]

# When user is at /checkout/success
RewriteRule ^checkout/success$ /checkout.php?success

# Force SSL on all pages
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

# Automatically includes bootstrap.php
php_value auto_prepend_file "/home/user/public_html/bootstrap.php"
```

If it is possible, can anyone suggest a more efficient way to do what I'm doing at the moment?

Comment: Are you facing any performance issues at all?

Comment: @anubhava, I don't know - I'm currently working on a local server so I don't know how to test it

Comment: @anubhava, can you tell me or give an example of how to test the performance?

Comment: I believe yahoo Dev network provides some nice tools for  benchmarking the web sites. You can search for them online.

Answer (score 0):

A large .htaccess will slow down your website performance. An empty .htaccess will slow down your website performance (if it is used). The only thing that will not slow down your website performance is not reading .htaccess by means of setting `AllowOverride None` in the directory configuration. Everything that can be done in .htaccess, can be done in the main configuration of the webserver.

Comment: It depends. You will have to do your own measurement.

Comment: Any .htaccess file will slow down your website.

Comment: Is it possible for you to think of any way that I can combine a few of the rules above together (a more efficient way)?

Answer (score 0):

Although any .htaccess file will slow things down, the extra time it takes is almost negligible in this case.

Off the top of my head, I can think of one way to improve performance.
Add the [L flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) to each rewriteRule.

Example:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404,L]
```

The L flag is like a `break` statement in a programming language. However, you have to be careful since no further rules will be processed after one is matched.